# Necessary condition for the existence of an inverse and continuous operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $E, F$ be normed spaces and $\gamma > 1$. If $T: E \to F$ is a continuous operator (not necessarily linear) and there is $c > 0$ such
that
$$||T(x)||_F \geq c||x||_E^{\gamma}, \quad \forall \ x \in E,$$
so there is the inverse operator $T^{-1}$? If so, is it possible to conclude that it is continuous?

Note: The motivation for this question is due to the fact that for $\gamma = 1$ the result is valid.

Comment: For $X=Y=\mathbb{R}$ the function $f(x)=x^2$ is not invertible. By the way for $\gamma=1$ the function $f(x)=|x|$ is not invertible. In general for $Y=\mathbb{R} $ the operator $T(x)=\|x\|^\gamma$ is not invertible.

Comment: Thanks! @RyszardSzwarc

Comment: If $E$ is a subspace of $F$ and $Tx=x$ for all $x \in E$ then the hypothesis holds with $\gamma =1$ but $T$ is not invertible as an operator from $E$ to $F$ (because it is not surjective).

Comment: The conclusion is true for linear operators, however there is no continuous linear operator satisfying the condition with $\gamma>1$ unless you restrict to $\|x\|\le 1.$ I mean that $T^{-1}$ is defined on the range of $T.$

Comment: @geetha290krm The conclusion holds in the sense that $T^{-1}$ is defined on the range of $T.$